# Two questions on trigonommetric sums and integrals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, exponential-sum

1. Is it true that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(mx)\sin(nx) \, dx = \delta (m-n) $ although using Euler formula I get a linear combination of $ \delta(m-n) $ and $ \delta (m+n)$?
2. What is the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sin(nx)$?

Here $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Clearly,
   $$\begin{align*}
   \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin mx \sin nx \; dx
   &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin mx \sin nx \; dx \\
   &= \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\cos (m-n)x - \cos(m+n)x ) \; dx \\
   &= \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{i(m-n)x} - e^{i(m+n)x}) \; dx \\
   &= \frac{\pi}{2}(\delta(m-n) - \delta(m+n)),
   \end{align*}$$
   in [*distribution sense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions). But If $m$ and $n$ are positive, no care is needed for the second term.
2. We have
   $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\sin nx = -\frac{1}{2}\tan \frac{x}{2}$$
   in *Abel summability sense*. Indeed,
   $$ \begin{align*}
   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\sin nx
   &= \lim_{s\to 0^{+}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\sin nx e^{-sn} \\
   &= \lim_{s\to 0^{+}} \Im \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-e^{ix-s})^{n} \\
   &= \lim_{s\to 0^{+}} \Im \left( \frac{1}{1 + e^{ix-s}} \right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{1 + e^{ix}} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{2}\tan \frac{x}{2}.
   \end{align*}$$
   In fact, this convergence can be reduced to *Cesaro summability sense*, though more calculation is required.

Comment: thank you very much :) ... for the cosine i knew how to evaluate it.. but not for the sine :)